# How to Differentiate Number 10 from '\n' in a Loop-Continuation Condition?

Tags: c++

I have the following portion of code:

```
cout << "Enter a series of integers: ";
cin >> integer;

while (integer != '\n')
{
    cout << ...

    cin >> integer;

} // end while
```

If the user enters 10, my loop is breaking because number 10 = '\n' value in decimal.

How can I get around this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you explain the intent of `while (integer != '\n')` ?  Do you mean to process all integers which are input on the same line?

Comment: For example, if user enters: 1 1 2 3 5 10, I want to loop through all entries until last digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempted code does not work because the operation `cin >> integer` extracts digits and converts them to an int. It cannot distinguish where the end of the line was.

Instead you should read a complete line, and then extract integers out of that line, e.g.:

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
std::istringstream iss(s);

int integer;
while ( iss >> integer )
{
    // do something with integer
}
```

Comment: You may also wish to check `if ( !std::cin )` after doing `getline`, that will be true if you have reached the end of the file.

Comment: This is really a neat solution! I never dealt with `istringstream` before but this is clean! Thanks for the effort,

Answer (score 2):

Consider reading the user's input into a `std::string` first.
If it's not the newline, convert to an `int` and do your work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::string integer;
    cout << "Enter a series of integers: ";
    cin >> integer;

    while (integer != "x") //<- can't be whitespace
    {
        cout << atoi(integer.c_str()) << std::endl;

        cin >> integer;

    }
}
```

Comment: Whitespace is skipped by the stream, so just hitting enter will not terminate the loop. Using getline(cin, integer) and then checking if the line is empty would do the job. Also, if I entered anything non-numeric, you would produce random output, too. I'd suggest using boost::lexical_cast on the input.

Comment: @agreed, agreed, and agreed.

Comment: It is impossible for `integer != "\n"` to be false

Comment: it is also impossible for `integer != " "` to be false. The `>>` extraction to a `std::string` skips all whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

By default, input streams will skip any whitespace, including newlines. In other words, you will never have a ten in the input value unless someone entered "10". The general way to handle input is to read until reading fails (e.g. due to EOF):

```
while(cin >> value)
{
    // use value here
}
// failure, EOF or garbage on input
```

Note that you will have to cin.clear() the stream before reading anything else afterwards, and that you still have the garbage in there that you have to cin.ignore(..). Maybe you want to use line-based input using getline() instead, and then simply check if the resulting string is empty or (try to) parse it as an integer otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
int integer = 0;
std::cout << "Enter a series of integers: ";
std::cin >> integer;

while (integer != '\n' || integer == 10) {// **this will not work, it's wrong!**
    std::cout << integer << std::endl;
    std::cin >> integer;
}//end while
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You enter 10, and the loop continues but you hit enter and it stops?

Comment: No problem. :) BTW, Dev C++ development itself has stalled ~10 years ago, so I'd consider upgrading. I'm currently evaluating the C Lion, which is in early beta but looks promising, otherwise there are plenty of other fish in the sea. Happy hacking!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks. I think I should learn harder to improve my programming skills.